# How to keep my relative paths with clean-css minifying?

Tags: gulp, gulp-clean-css

Why does gulp code below remove my relative paths?

I am using [clean-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-clean-css):

```
gulp.task('build-css', function() {
    return gulp.src([
        'style.css',
        ])
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}))
        .pipe(concat('bundle.min.css'))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./maps'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(livereload());
});
```

Original css:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('../fonts/social-media/icomoon.eot?mh2h47');
  src:  url('../fonts/social-media/icomoon.eot?mh2h47#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/social-media/icomoon.ttf?mh2h47') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/social-media/icomoon.woff?mh2h47') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/social-media/icomoon.svg?mh2h47#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

After minifying with gulp:

```css
@font-face{font-family:icomoon;src:url(fonts/social-media/icomoon.eot?mh2h47);src:url(fonts/social-media/icomoon.eot?mh2h47#iefix)
```

How can I keep these relative paths?

Comment: Please link to the exact plugin you're using.

Comment: @EmileBergeron i have updated my question.

Comment: Just guessing, but try setting the rebase: false option in your cleanCSS options ala: cleanCSS(debug: true, rebase: false})  and report back if that helps.

Comment: @Mark it works with that option. thanks! they should have this in the doc!

Comment: Great, I've made it into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the rebase option to false (true is the default) so that your paths are not modified by cleanCSS.

```
.pipe(cleanCSS( {debug: true, rebase: false} )
```